# After rearranging field order in a view, how do I export this modification in features?

Tags: views, entities, features

I am using drupal 7, I rearranged the order of the fields in a view, using the contextual menu link 'raerrange' (see image). But now I am not able to export this modification into the feature related to this view. The feature is still in 'default' status. Which is the feature component that is storing this modification? Which component should I add to the feature?

Any help will be really appreciate.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there was no component to add to the feature: the modification was already there even if the feature status didn't change. 
The field order is stored into the file: 'feature_name.views_default.inc'.  In order to update the file with the modification, the feature must be 'generated'. (Go to feature --> recreate--> advanced options --> generate feature)